# Binding listbox maxHeight to parent actual

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I am having some trouble getting the binding of a `lisbox` `height` to work. I have a user control that holds a `listbox`, this box is dynamically populated on the fly but it seems that if too many items are added it extends past the boundaries of the parent objects and refuses to stop and use the scoll bar...

```
   <UserControl x:Class="TransaltionModule.Views.NoteView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding noteList}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Type :" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Width="65"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding noteType}" Width="auto" IsEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBlock Text="Date :" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Width="65"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding timeStamp}" Width="auto" IsEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding text}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

If i hardcode the `maxheight` property everything works as intended, but with the multiple display resolutions I will be working against that is not a solution I can use. Can anyone recommend a fix

Comment: You should need any of this when the ListBox is properly place in the right parent. Can you show the surrounding Tag(s) ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The surrounding is only a UserControl, which is injected using Prism5.0 (MEF) into a regionView this listbox is the upper most tag outside of the <usercontrol> tag

Comment: I hope it's inside that <UserControl>. But consider using a <Grid> or <DockPanel> to encapsulate  the ListBox. So much more elegant than binding to ActualHeight. You can then also remove all those ="Stretch" nonsense.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yea that didnt help much. same issue. I have updated the question with the full xaml file so it would be more clear

Comment: The provided xaml should work as requird, I'd like to hear if @micbobo's answer works. If not, post the xaml holding the UserControl. Any Telerik/DevExpress or similar stuff?

Comment: Henk should be correct. The only explanation for weird sizing might be some odd implicit styling that changes how items are layed out; however, you cannot really style Grids, so the problem should be higher up.

Comment: @asuppa Did you manage to make it work ?

Comment: @micbobo unfortunately I did not, I stepped away from this for a while so I coud accomplish other work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `bind` it to an element by using `Path=ActualHeight`

For this to work don't forget to name the `Grid` containing the `Listbox`

Try something like this :

```
<Grid x:Name = "grdListBoxTest">
    <ListBox x:Name="lstBoxTest" 
             MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=grdListBoxTest, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <!-- Your Listbox Stuff Here -->
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

By doing this you link the height of the `Listbox` to it's parent `Grid`. That way if the grid's size changes the  `MaxHeight` of the `Listbox` will change.